# How to check error messages from perror?

Tags: c++, stdout, stderr

I know this a simple but i couldn't get it.

I am using OS- Ubuntu. The following code has been written in mysql source code (in sql_parse.cc file). I need to check the perror error message. How can i get those messages?
I don't think this error messages will be shown in the console where i am running mysql client/ server?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

{ 
string hashed;
int sockfd, n;
char buf[MAXDATASIZE], url[MAXDATASIZE], ack[6];
struct hostent *he;
struct sockaddr_in remote_addr;

if ((he=gethostbyname("localhost")) == NULL) { // get the host info
    perror("gethostbyname");
    exit(1);
    }

if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("socket");
    exit(1);
    }

remote_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; // host byte order
remote_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT); // short, network byte order
remote_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)he->h_addr);
memset(&(remote_addr.sin_zero), '\0', 8); // zero the rest of the struct

if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&remote_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
    perror("connect");
    exit(1);
    }
```

Please help me....

Comment: Are you asking where the message gets written to, so that the DB administrator can find it in the logs? Or are you asking how the *program* can discover whether `perror` was used elsewhere in the program?

Comment: I want to check if there is any error in the above condition then `perror` will print the error message so where can i get those messages?

Answer (score 0):

1. perror function is one of the **standart streams**.
2. It gives output to stderr. **You can redirect stderr output to a
   custom place** (like a file or stdout-console) in Linux.

For example, after you compile your code, let's say a program file created as "myprogram"

if you run this file as in this way:

```
./myprogram 2>&1
```

you can see perror errors **in your console**.

*For your spesific situation*, you need to read Mysql error log. In **Debian**, Mysql Config file says this:

> Error logging goes to syslog due to
>   /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf.

So that, **you can read these errors via reading syslog file**. You can read syslog via a text editor, or tail, less, etc:

```
sudo gedit /var/log/syslog
```

Comment: I will run the `mysql` program using `mysql -u root -p` ,then password.So where can i write `2>&1` ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand it very well. Mysql error codes goes to syslog. You can read syslog via any text editor. Such as "sudo gedit /var/log/syslog"

Comment: The above socket code has been used in PHP source code also..So i have to see the `stderr` console..

Comment: I've edited my answer, it includes your situation now. By the way, you can give positive votes if any answers was helpful for you.

Comment: I have checked my syslog but it's not showing the error message..Any other solution

Comment: I've looked at my.cnf in Ubuntu. It seems log file is different in Ubuntu. Here is the file you are looking for: /var/log/mysql/error.log

Comment: error.log asserts only server log like when the server was started,is there any problem, what are the resources it has used etc etc...No `perror` message error..